# Calculating time difference between two 24H time in php

Tags: php

I'm struggling to calculate time difference between two 24 hour format. The data extracted from my database is like this:

```
$timein = "09:00";
$timeout = "17:00";
$timediff = $timein - $timeout
```

As above, how do I get the `$timediff = 8`?

Comment: Try the DateTime class in PHP - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: My advice is to store the dates in the database as unix timestamps, which are basically seconds, so you will be able to do mathematical operations on those dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
$timediff = date("H",strtotime($timein) - strtotime($timeout));
```

You can also change to format of the result, 
check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

If you first set them to full dates:

```
$timein = "09:00";
$timeout = "17:00";
$datein = strtotime(date("Y-m-d ".$timein);
$dateout = strtotime(date("Y-m-d ".$timeout);
```

So, in fact the date you are using (todays date) can be any other date given since it's all about the time between the hours. Then you can create the php `date` function:

```
$hourIn = date("G", $datein); // = 9
$hourOut = date("G", $dateout); // = 17
```

Followed by simple math:

```
$diff = $hourOut - $hourIn; // = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime() for time calculation.

```
$timein = strtotime('09:00');
$timeout = strtotime('17:00');
$timediff = $timein - $timeout;
echo 'Time: '.date('H:i:s', $timediff);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Break the problem down into two steps.**

1. Convert each time into a number of seconds since midnight.
2. Calculate the difference between two times.

This breaks the larger problem down into basic problems which can be solved more easily.  It is a very valuable tool in the programmer's belt.

For the second part, be sure to handle midnight the way you need to for your data.  Perhaps if the timeout is before the timein, then you'll need to add 24 hours to the total?  That's just a guess, because I do not know your data.